# C# Winforms DataTable cannot find the row with a specified id

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, find

I have a data table. I add a row to that data table. And i want to get the values of datagridview's selected row to some text box which data table is bound to. In my datagridview selection changed method i call find method of rows collection of datatable. But it gives me NullReferenceException.

```
        private void dgvRecipeMaterial_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && isDgvRecipeMaterialReady)
            {
                int rowIndex = dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                object[] data = dtrecetemalzemejoin.Rows[0].ItemArray;
                object[] items = dtrecetemalzemejoin.Rows.Find(id).ItemArray;
                .
                .
                .
                .
```

I looked to my id via debugger. Its value is 1166. And when i debug i see there is an item with the id 1166 from the data array. But find method cant find the id 1166. There is no problem if there is more then one record in the data table. What is the problem. data array has the id but find method cant find it.

Comment: Which line of code give you `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: `object[] items = dtrecetemalzemejoin.Rows.Find(id).ItemArray;`

Comment: Show code how you get data to `dtrecetemalzemejoin`

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Rows.Find` method searching for a rows by columns from `DataTable.PrimaryKey` property.
Check if your datatable primarykey contain column where your `ID` value is.
[From MSDN: DataTable.PrimaryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx)
If `PrimaryKey` columns did not set. Then before using `Find` method you set it like this:

```
dtrecetemalzemejoin.PrimaryKey = {dtrecetemalzemejoin.Columns[0]};
//or may be better will be using a name of column
dtrecetemalzemejoin.PrimaryKey = {dtrecetemalzemejoin.Columns["IDColumn"]};
```

Comment: If `PrimaryKey` contain column where `id` value is, then your code working fine for me

Comment: @MOD, is "id" column also typed as int?

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code i was also getting same error

```
 private void dgvRecipeMaterial_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows.Count > 0 && isDgvRecipeMaterialReady)
            {
                int rowIndex = dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                string id = Convert.ToString(dgvRecipeMaterial.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                object[] data = dtrecetemalzemejoin.Rows[0].ItemArray;
                object[] items = dtrecetemalzemejoin.Rows.Find(id).ItemArray;
                .
                .
```